# Install custom nodejs module from hard disk

Tags: node.js, git, npm

Is there a way to install a custom node module without having a reference to a repository (like git)?
Only installing it by copying the files on hard disk and install it there?

*UPDATE*
the problem was that the package.json pointed to a git repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [manual states](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html), `npm install` supports `npm install <folder>` where `<folder>` is just a local directory where the module is stored.

> `npm install <folder>`:
>
> Install a package that is sitting in a folder on the filesystem.